# Is there an Eclipse plugin that can replace the use of external tools such as Putty and WinScp

Tags: eclipse, plugins, remote-server

Every time I want to run my project on the remote server, I need to export it from Eclipse as a jar file, to transfer the file from my local machine to the remote server using WinSCP and then to use Putty to run it on the remote server. I am wondering is there a more suitable way of handling this, e.g. an Eclipse plugin that allows me to perform this straight from Eclipse.

Comment: Couldn'tyou create a program to do all that for you, and call it with a few parameters everytime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality is present in Eclipse, called `Remote Systems Explorer`.

1. Open the `Remote Systems` view by going to `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Other...`.
2. Then right click in this view and select on `New connection...`.
3. Select `SSH Only` as remote system type and click `Next`.
4. Fill in the necessary information such as hostname and connection name and click `Finish`.
5. Select the `Connector` node you just created from the `Remote Systems` view and choose `Connect...`. Enter your credentials and press `Ok`.

If you managed to log in, you will see a green arrow on the node indicating you are connected.

You can right click either `Shells` or `Terminals` and choose `Launch Shell/Terminal`. A new `Remote Shell` or `Terminal` should appear where you can type in commands.

It is also possible to remotely create files, open/edit and save them from within Eclipse.

More documentation can be found in the [Eclipse RSE manual](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.user%2Fgettingstarted%2Fg_start.html).